# Expand pandas DataFrame column into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a `DataFrame` such that:

```
pd.DataFrame( {"name" : "John", 
               "days" : [[1, 3, 5, 7]]
              })
```

gives this structure:

```
           days  name
0  [1, 3, 5, 7]  John
```

How do expand it to the following?

```
   days  name
0     1  John
1     3  John
2     5  John
3     7  John
```

Comment: I don't fully understand why you wan to do this? Is it because you have a dictionary like that and you want to turn it into a dataframe? And, in the column `name` you want to have the same value all the way through?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use `df.itertuples` to iterate through each row, and use a list comprehension to reshape the data into the desired form:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : ["John", "Eric"], 
               "days" : [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2,4]]})
result = pd.DataFrame([(d, tup.name) for tup in df.itertuples() for d in tup.days])
print(result)
```

yields

```
   0     1
0  1  John
1  3  John
2  5  John
3  7  John
4  2  Eric
5  4  Eric
```

---

[Divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203702/190597), `using_repeat`, is fastest:

```
In [48]: %timeit using_repeat(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 834 µs per loop

In [5]: %timeit using_itertuples(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.43 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit using_apply(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 379 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit using_append(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.59 s per loop
```

---

Here is the setup used for the above benchmark:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10**3
df = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=N), 
                    "days" : [np.random.randint(10, size=np.random.randint(5))
                              for i in range(N)]})

def using_itertuples(df):
    return  pd.DataFrame([(d, tup.name) for tup in df.itertuples() for d in tup.days])

def using_repeat(df):
    lens = [len(item) for item in df['days']]
    return pd.DataFrame( {"name" : np.repeat(df['name'].values,lens), 
                          "days" : np.concatenate(df['days'].values)})

def using_apply(df):
    return (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.days), axis=1)
            .stack()
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
            .to_frame('day')
            .join(df['name']))

def using_append(df):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
    for i,r in df.iterrows():
        for e in r.days:
            new_r = r.copy()
            new_r.days = e
            df2 = df2.append(new_r)
    return df2
```

Comment: Bothering you, as I just modified mine to replace `np.concatenate` with `np.hstack`. Seems like it's a bit faster. Do you mind, updating the timings with it? :)

Comment: @Divakar: I'm astonished. That's quite an improvement!

Comment: Appreciate the updates! Well I am surprised to see np.hstack being faster than np.concatenate, as I was under the impression that all those hstack and vstacks are derived from np.concatenate. Maybe with pandas, it's doing optimizations? Not sure!

Comment: `np.concatenate(df['days'].values)` seems to be even faster than `np.hstack(df['days'])`.

Comment: Ah that's interesting and sort of makes sense I guess. So going through the route of NumPy array of obj dtype is better! Hmm.

Comment: Amazing the speedup now, lovely!

Comment: `np.concatenate(df['Days'])` is much slower than `np.concatenate(df['Days'].values)` because [under the hood](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L600) `np.concatenate` loops through the items in `df['Days']` using `PySequence_GetItem(df['Days'], iarrays)`, which is equivalent to `df['Days'][iarrays]`. This treats `iarray` as an index label, not an ordinal integer index. Looking up an index label is much slower than ordinal integer indexing. Performance disaster ensues.

Comment: `np.hstack(df['Days'])` is pretty fast because this [converts `df['Days']` to a list](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/shape_base.py#L283). So the indexing is again ordinal integer indexing.

Comment: So, `np.concatenate` wasn't clever enough at it. Thanks for the insights there and digging in, appreciate it!

Answer (score 21):

New since pandas 0.25 you can use the function `explode()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : "John", 
               "days" : [[1, 3, 5, 7]]})

print(df.explode('days'))
```

prints

```
   name days
0  John    1
0  John    3
0  John    5
0  John    7
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's something with NumPy -

```
lens = [len(item) for item in df['days']]
df_out = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : np.repeat(df['name'].values,lens), 
               "days" : np.hstack(df['days'])
              })
```

As pointed in [`@unutbu's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203536/3293881) `np.concatenate(df['days'].values)` would be faster than `np.hstack(df['days'])`.

It uses a loop-comprehension to extract the lengths of each `'days'` element, which must be minimal runtime-wise.

Sample run -

```
>>> df
           days  name
0  [1, 3, 5, 7]  John
1        [2, 4]  Eric
>>> lens = [len(item) for item in df['days']]
>>> pd.DataFrame( {"name" : np.repeat(df['name'].values,lens), 
...                "days" : np.hstack(df['days'])
...               })
   days  name
0     1  John
1     3  John
2     5  John
3     7  John
4     2  Eric
5     4  Eric
```

Answer (score 7):

A 'native' pandas solution - we unstack the column into a series, then join back on based on index:

```
import pandas as pd #import
x2 = x.days.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack() #make an unstackeded series, x2
x.drop('days', axis = 1).join(pd.DataFrame(x2.reset_index(level=0, drop=True))) #drop the days column, join to the x2 series
```

Answer (score 2):

another solution:

```
In [139]: (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.days), axis=1)
   .....:    .stack()
   .....:    .reset_index(level=1, drop=1)
   .....:    .to_frame('day')
   .....:    .join(df['name'])
   .....: )
Out[139]:
   day  name
0    1  John
0    3  John
0    5  John
0    7  John
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! A slightly different need: what could be modified to leave NaN values to the frame when the arrays are like `[val, None, None, val2, None ...]` and they differ in size?

Comment: Self-reply: first replace the `None`s with some placeholder so pandas won't freak out. Then remove the `reset_index`. Move join before stack and optionally set the name-field as index before stacking to avoid repeating it. Afterwards replace placeholders with NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Probably somehow like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)
for i,r in df.iterrows():
    for e in r.days:
        new_r = r.copy()
        new_r.days = e
        df2 = df2.append(new_r)
df2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203702/3734503), wrote it as a wrapper function to flatten a column, handling `np.nan` and DataFrames with multiple columns

```
def flatten_column(df, column_name):
     repeat_lens = [len(item) if item is not np.nan else 1 for item in df[column_name]]
     df_columns = list(df.columns)
     df_columns.remove(column_name)
     expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.drop(column_name, axis=1).values, repeat_lens, axis=0), columns=df_columns)
     flat_column_values = np.hstack(df[column_name].values)
     expanded_df[column_name] = flat_column_values
     expanded_df[column_name].replace('nan', np.nan, inplace=True)
     return expanded_df
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you ended up here, searching for a solution with multiple columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {"name" : "John", 
               "days" : [[1, 3, 5, 7]]
               "values": [[10,20,30,40]]
              })
print(df)

           days  name values
0  [1, 3, 5, 7]  John [10,20,30,40]
```

the command:

```
print(df.explode(list(('days', 'values'))
```

will give the output:

```
   name days values
0  John    1 10
0  John    3 20
0  John    5 30
0  John    7 40
```

Note that the "expanded" columns must have the same length.