# Explode column of list to multiple rows

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I want to expand the list in a certain column (in the example column_x) to multiple rows.

So

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': ['a_1', 'a_2'], 
                   'column_b': ['b_1', 'b_2'], 
                   'column_x': [['c_1', 'c_2'], ['d_1', 'd_2']]
                  })
```

shall be transformed from

```
    column_a    column_b    column_x
0   a_1         b_1         [c_1, c_2]
1   a_2         b_2         [d_1, d_2]
```

to

```
    column_a    column_b    column_x
0   a_1         b_1         c_1
1   a_1         b_1         c_2
2   a_2         b_2         d_1
3   a_2         b_2         d_2
```

The code I have so far does exactly this, and it does it [fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203352/expand-pandas-dataframe-column-into-multiple-rows/38203702#38203702).

```
lens = [len(item) for item in df['column_x']]
pd.DataFrame( {"column_a" : np.repeat(df['column_a'].values, lens), 
               "column_b" : np.repeat(df['column_b'].values, lens), 
               "column_x" : np.concatenate(df['column_x'].values)})
```

However, I have lots of columns. Is there a neat and elegant solution for repeating the whole data frame without specifying each column again?

Comment: I think here is main problem if all columns have same `dtypes`. Because if use `df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': [1, 2], 
                   'column_b': ['b_1', 'b_2'], 
                   'column_x': [['c_1', 'c_2'], ['d_1', 'd_2']]
                  })` then both solutions get different outputs - check it by `print (df1.dtypes)` vs `print (df.dtypes)`. Here is main problem numpy cast all dtypes to same, so more general solution is repeat `index` and if same `dtypes` of all column  is possible use `cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ` solution too. It depends of data.

Comment: This is an important remark! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat index values:

```
lens = df['column_x'].str.len()
a = np.repeat(df.index.values, lens)
print (a)
[0 0 1 1]

df = df.loc[a].assign(column_x=np.concatenate(df['column_x'].values)).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  column_a column_b column_x
0      a_1      b_1      c_1
1      a_1      b_1      c_2
2      a_2      b_2      d_1
3      a_2      b_2      d_2
```

Comment: Repeating index values is a pain, isn't it? Makes cell coords non-unique.

Comment: @smci - You are right, but if need not change all dtypes to strings it is good solution

Comment: jezrael there's no need to: `df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` will reindex the df, with integers. (Mind you it will invalidate any existing variables storing indices).

Comment: From a performance perspective: This solution is almost double as fast as the solution of @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ.

Answer (score 8):

#### Pandas >= 0.25

Pandas can do this in a single function call via [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode).

```
df.explode('column_x')

  column_a column_b column_x
0      a_1      b_1      c_1
0      a_1      b_1      c_2
1      a_2      b_2      d_1
1      a_2      b_2      d_2
```

Note that you can only explode a Series/DataFrame on one column.

---

#### Pandas < 0.25

Call `np.repeat` along the 0<sup>th</sup> axis for every column *besides* `column_x`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    df.drop('column_x', 1).values.repeat(df['column_x'].str.len(), axis=0),
    columns=df.columns.difference(['column_x'])
)
df1['column_x'] = np.concatenate(df['column_x'].values)

df1

  column_a column_b column_x
0      a_1      b_1      c_1
1      a_1      b_1      c_2
2      a_2      b_2      d_1
3      a_2      b_2      d_2
```