# Expand pandas dataframe by replacing cell value with a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this below:

```
A B C
a b c
d e f
```

where A B and C are column names. Now i have a list:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

I want to replace the c in column C with list such as dataframe expands for all value of list, like below:

```
A B C
a b 1
a b 2
a b 3
d e f
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I can always do this by running it in for loop, but need some efficient solution for large datasets

Comment: Do `df.loc[df.index[0], 'C'] = mylist` and then follow instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147996/explode-column-of-list-to-multiple-rows/49148066#49148066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  a  b  c
3  t  e  w
mylist = [1,2,3]

idx1 = df.index[df.C == 'c']
df = df.loc[idx1.repeat(len(mylist))].assign(C=mylist * len(idx1)).append(df[df.C != 'c'])
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  a  b  1
0  a  b  2
0  a  b  3
2  a  b  1
2  a  b  2
2  a  b  3
1  d  e  f
3  t  e  w
```

Comment: In this case it works good, but in case when there are more than 1 rows with same value 'c' , then the code breaks with error: Length of values does not match length of index.

Comment: @Shubzumt - Yes, solution was wrong, please check now.

Comment: Worked like charm! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this,

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
x=pd.DataFrame({'mylist':mylist})
x['C']='c'
res= pd.merge(df,x,on=['C'],how='left')
res['mylist']=res['mylist'].fillna(res['C'])
```

For further,

```
del res['C']
res.rename(columns={"mylist":"C"},inplace=True)
print res
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  a  b  1
1  a  b  2
2  a  b  3
3  d  e  f
```

Comment: the inner join method is good here, but in large datasets it takes a lot of time, thats why I am looking for something efficient.