# Rearrange dataframe to turn multiple columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in this format, but with hundreds more rows and columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                        'col2': ['1, 5, 10', '1, 10, 20', '1, 5, 10'],
                      'col3': ['2, 10, 20', '2, 10, 20', 'None']})
```

Instead of having so many columns, I want to rearrange the df so each value in `col1` is duplicated across many rows, and rearrange the values in this way:

```
dfoutput = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
         'col2': ['1, 5, 10', '2, 10, 20', '1, 10, 20', '2, 10, 20', '1, 5, 10']})
```

I tried using combinations of `df.melt` and `df.groupby` but I'm getting nowhere. I also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203352/expand-pandas-dataframe-column-into-multiple-rows), but I have hundreds of columns to split instead of 1 (and they aren't tuples). I also fiddled with the answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147996/explode-column-of-list-to-multiple-rows?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the df organization is different enough that I couldn't get it to work for my df.

Comment: `df.melt('col1')
`

Comment: Of course! I had to add `.replace(to_replace='None', value=np.nan).dropna()` to get rid of the rows with `None`, but that works.