# Create a DataFrame form a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I'm want to create a Pandas dataframe from a list of tuples in Python.

```
my_list=[('integer_1',['value1', 'value2']),
         ('integer_2',['value1', 'value2']),
         ...
         ('integer_n-1',['value1', 'value2']),
         ('integer_n',['value1', 'value2'])
        ]
```

My DataFrame (with df.shape = [2*n,2] ) must be like this:

```
  integer   value
0 integer_1 value_1
1 integer_1 value_2
2 integer_2 value_1
3 integer_2 value_1
...
2n-1 integer_n value_1
2n integer_n value_2
```

Any suggests?

Comment: much better if you supplied actual numbers to work with. string processing will be different from numbers. We cant say if value1 will be strings/numbers. specifics are much better.

Comment: does the value1 and value2 same for all the elements in list?

Comment: Not always @komatiraju032

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203352/expand-pandas-dataframe-column-into-multiple-rows

Comment: @monte, I think it works too. I have around 50k tuples on my list. Do you think that answer is more efficient than the one published by YOBEN_S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `explode`

```
df=pd.DataFrame(my_list,columns=['int','value']).explode('value')
           int   value
0    integer_1  value1
0    integer_1  value2
1    integer_2  value1
1    integer_2  value2
2  integer_n-1  value1
2  integer_n-1  value2
3    integer_n  value1
3    integer_n  value2
```

Comment: it works. I would add this line at the end: df.reset_index(drop=True).