# Looking for same values in more than one columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the next information

```
      Syndromes                                 Genes
0   1p36 microdeletion syndrome     RP11-34P13.7; CICP27; AL627309.1; RP11-34P13.1...
1   Cri du Chat Syndrome            ICMT; LINC00337; HES3; GPR153; ACOT7; RP1-202O...
...
```

I would like to know if there are some genes involve in more one syndromews.

Is there an easy approach to do that?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Please provide a good sample of data with the expected output and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you want to get the occurence of Genes in various symptoms.

You can count the symptoms where a particular genes occur by 1st `exploding` and then `groupby` `count`.

```
df1 = df.assign(gene=df['Genes'].str.split('; ')).explode('gene')
df1.groupby('gene')['Syndromes'].count()
```

---

```
gene
ACOT7           1
AL627309.1      1
CICP27          2
GPR153          1
HES3            1
ICMT            1
LINC00337       1
RP1-202O        1
RP11-34P13.1    1
RP11-34P13.7    1
Name:       Syndromes, dtype: int64
```

if you want to list the name of symptoms then do :

```
df1.groupby('gene')['Syndromes'].apply(list)
```

---

```
gene
ACOT7                                  [1   Cri du Chat Syndrome]
AL627309.1                      [0   1p36 microdeletion syndrome]
CICP27          [0   1p36 microdeletion syndrome, 1   Cri du C...
GPR153                                 [1   Cri du Chat Syndrome]
HES3                                   [1   Cri du Chat Syndrome]
ICMT                                   [1   Cri du Chat Syndrome]
LINC00337                              [1   Cri du Chat Syndrome]
RP1-202O                               [1   Cri du Chat Syndrome]
RP11-34P13.1                    [0   1p36 microdeletion syndrome]
RP11-34P13.7                    [0   1p36 microdeletion syndrome]
Name:       Syndromes, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ManoloDominguezBecerra: For using `explode` pandas version should be `>= 0.25`

Comment: I am doing some upgrading and then I will let you know if this works.

Comment: I have upgraded my pandas and I have the versionb pandas-1.1.3 but still getting the error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @ManoloDominguezBecerra Do `pip freeze | grep pandas` and check the version I think you may need to restart your kernel if you are working on notebook

Comment: or try `df.assign(gene=df['Genes'].str.split('; ')).to_frame().explode('gene')`

Comment: @Pygirl Here is one way of doing without using `explode`, `pd.value_counts(np.hstack(df['Genes'].str.split('; ')))`

Comment: Absolutely right I restarted my kernel and then it worked. Also the second suggestion by Shubhan Sharma worked as well. Thanks!!

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: what about `np.concatenate` (although almost same) :P  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38203536/6660373

Answer (score 1):

From your source data sample I see that you have actually only **2** columns:

- *Syndromes* - the syndrome name,
- *Genes* - a **list** of gene names involved in this syndrome (separated
  with *'; '* string).

Assume that your source DataFrame contains:

```
    Syndromes                                           Genes
0  Syndrome_1    XXX-13.7; XXX-44.2; AL627309.1; RP11-34P13.1
1  Syndrome_2  ICMT; LINC00337; HES3; GPR153; ACOT7; RP1-202O
2  Syndrome_3                        ICMT; XXX-13.7; XXX-22.9
3  Syndrome_4                         XXX-13.7; GPR153; ACOT7
4  Syndrome_5                               XXX-44.2; RP1-202
```

The first step is to convert each **string** (containing the gene list)
into an actual **list**:

```
df.Genes = df.Genes.str.split('; ')
```

Print the source *df* before and after this operation to see the difference.

Then, to see in which syndromes is involved each gene, filtering out single
involvements:

1. Define a function generating a list of syndromes for a group of rows:

   ```
   def synList(grp):
       if grp.index.size > 1:
           return grp.Syndromes.to_list()
       return np.nan
   ```
2. Generate the result:

   ```
   result = df.explode(column='Genes').groupby('Genes').apply(synList).dropna()
   ```

   Steps:

   - `df.explode(column='Genes')` - Convert each row into a couple of
     rows, each with a **single** gene.
   - `groupby('Genes')` - Group the above result by *Genes* column.
   - `apply(synList)` - Apply the above function (to each group).
   - `dropna()` - Drop rows for single occurrences.

For my source data the result is the following *Series*:

```
Genes
ACOT7                   [Syndrome_2, Syndrome_4]
GPR153                  [Syndrome_2, Syndrome_4]
ICMT                    [Syndrome_2, Syndrome_3]
XXX-13.7    [Syndrome_1, Syndrome_3, Syndrome_4]
XXX-44.2                [Syndrome_1, Syndrome_5]
dtype: object
```

The index (left column) is the gene name and the value (right column,
containing a list) is a list of syndromes where the gene occurs.

Comment: Wow it looks like I am reading a manual with proper instructions mentioned. +1

Comment: The code I wrote is quite concise, but reading it by somebody with
small experience in *Python* or *Pandas* can be difficult.
So it is advisable to put some explanation concerning each step of
such a chained instruction.